# Tangent space of the $z$ axis

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I want to find the tangent space of the $z$-axis a some point $p\in \mathbb{R^3}$. If $(0,0,c)$ is some point on the $z$ axis, is $T_pZ=\{(0,0,zc)|z\in R\}$? $Z$ here is for the $z$ axis. I know this is a very basic question but any help is very very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. In fact, $Z$ is a line and the tangent space must be a line, too, as $Z$ has dimension $1$. Now two intersecting lines are tangent if and only if they coincide.

Comment: Not quite. What if $c=0$?